# Custom treetableview order

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I have a treetableview which multiple columns. I like to order only by one column so I apply:

```
treetbvItems.getSortOrder().add("categoria");
```

This order data by column "categoria" alphabetical but I want to apply my custom order.

For example, if category can be onew of this values: animals, computers, shoes, vehicles... with above sentence, I get tree order by this way:

1. animals
2. computers
3. shoes
4. vehicles

but if I want (can be any other custom orther):

1. computers
2. shoes
3. animals
4. vehicles

Is possible or not to do whith JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you really mean

```
TreeTableColumn<String> categoria ; 
// ...

treebvItems.getSortOrder().add(categoria);
```

since the code you posted won't compile.

You can control the ordering for a particular column by [setting a `Comparator` on the column](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#comparatorProperty).

The [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) defines a `compareTo(String, String)` method that returns an negative `int` if the first argument comes before the second, a positive `int` if the second argument comes before the first, and 0 if they are equal.

So you could do something like:

```
categoria.setComparator((cat1, cat2) -> {
    if (cat1.equals(cat2)) {
        return 0 ;
    }
    if ("computers".equals(cat1)) {
        return -1 ;
    }
    if ("computers".equals(cat2)) {
        return 1 ;
    }
    if ("shoes".equals(cat1)) {
        return -1 ;
    }
    if ("shoes".equals(cat2)) {
        return 1 ;
    }
    if ("animals".equals(cat1)) {
        return -1 ;
    }
    if ("animals".equals(cat2)) {
       return 1 ;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown categories: "+cat1+", "+cat2);
}
```

Note that if you have a fixed set of categories, you should probably use an [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of a `String`. The "natural" order of an `Enum` is defined by its declaration order.

Comment: Ok, yes I try with enum because categoria values are taken from a DB.